# Node.js split JSON Object Per a Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a Node 10+ script that needs to split a JSON object. I have looked for various solutions but none fits my particular needs. Here is my object:

```
[ 
[ 
  {agent_id: '123',   start: '10-05-2018'},
  { agent_id: '123', start: '10-05-2018'} 
],
[ 
  { agent_id: '456', start: '10-04-2018'},
  { agent_id: '456', start: '10-05-2018'} 
] 
]
```

So there are two elements/nodes; one has `agent_id` of '123' and the other has '456'. But what needs to happen is if the `start` is the same in an element then no need to split, as in the case of `agent_id` of '123'. But in the case of `start` being different than that needs to split. So the end result in the case of the above object should be something like below. As you can see, there are three elements to the result. I have a look into 'map' or 'set' or other examples but none apply in my case. And hence I am here.

Thank you!

```
 [
    [
     { agent_id: '123',   start: '10-05-2018'},
     { agent_id: '123', start: '10-05-2018'}
    ],
    [ { agent_id: '456', start: '10-04-2018'}],
    [ { agent_id: '456', start: '10-05-2018'}]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupBy` method from `lodash` package:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const items = [ 
[ 
  {agent_id: '123',   start: '10-05-2018'},
  { agent_id: '123', start: '10-05-2018'} 
],
[ 
  { agent_id: '456', start: '10-04-2018'},
  { agent_id: '456', start: '10-05-2018'} 
] 
]

const result = items
  .map(x => Object.values(_.groupBy(x, el => `${el.agent_id}:${el.start}`)))
  .reduce((curr, next) => curr.concat(next), [])
```

Comment: Thank you. Going to install Lodash and give your Answer a try!

Comment: Yes sir. This is going to work! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using lodash, you can try the following code in vanilla JS:

```
let input = [
    [
        { agent_id: '123', start: '10-05-2018' },
        { agent_id: '123', start: '10-05-2018' }
    ],
    [
        { agent_id: '456', start: '10-04-2018' },
        { agent_id: '456', start: '10-05-2018' }
    ]
];

function recursiveFunc(arrItem, resultingArr) {
    if (Array.isArray(arrItem) && arrItem.length) {
        let matchArr = []; let restArr = [];
        arrItem.every((v) => {
            if (!(v.start === arrItem[0].start)) {
                restArr.push(v);
            } else {
                matchArr.push(v);
            }
            return v.start === arrItem[0].start;
        });
        if (matchArr.length) resultingArr.push(matchArr);
        if (restArr.length > 1) {
            return recursiveFunc(restArr, resultingArr);
        } else {
            if (restArr.length) resultingArr.push(restArr);
        }
    }
}

let resultingArr = [];
input.forEach(arrItem => {
    recursiveFunc(arrItem, resultingArr);
});
console.log(resultingArr);
```

Comment: Hi, a non-Lodash solution would have been better. I had already accepted the first Answer which works,  and if issues would come back to this topic. Thank you very much!!